# Как получить запросом POST Set-cookie используя retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

RegistrationBody.class:

```
public class RegistrationBody {

    public String email;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String password;
}
```

RegistrationResponce.class:

```
public class RegistrationResponse {

    public String cookie;
}
```

Запрос:

```
@POST("/signup/")
    Call<RegistrationResponse> registerUser(@Body RegistrationBody registrationBody);
```

Для авторизации пользователя я передаю POST-запросом поля email, first_name, last_name, password. Этот запрос должен возвратить мне Set-cookie, но не возвращает:

```
requestInterface = Controller.getApi();
                RegistrationBody registrationBody = new RegistrationBody();
                registrationBody.email = email;
                registrationBody.first_name = firstName;
                registrationBody.last_name = lastName;
                registrationBody.password = newPassword;
                requestInterface.registerUser(registrationBody).enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
                        Log.d("myLogs", "Response" + response.raw().headers());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("myLogs", "response onFailure");
                        Log.d("myLogs", "Throwable: " + t.toString());
                    }
                });
```

AddCookiesInterceptor.class:

```
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    public static final String PREF_COOKIES = "PREF_COOKIES";
    private Context context;

    public AddCookiesInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

        HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet<String>) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getStringSet(PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<String>());

        String cookiestring = "";
        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            String[] parser = cookie.split(";");
            cookiestring = cookiestring + parser[0] + "; ";
        }
        builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookiestring);

        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}
```

ReceivedCookiesInterceptor.class:

```
public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private Context context;
    public ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
            HashSet<String> cookies = (HashSet<String>) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", new HashSet<String>());

            for (String header : originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
                cookies.add(header);
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor memes = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
            memes.putStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", cookies).apply();
            memes.commit();
        }

        return originalResponse;
    }
}
```

Добавила клиент:

```
private static Context context;

    public Controller (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static RequestInterface getApi() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        builder.addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(Controller.context));
        builder.addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(context));

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        return requestInterface;
```

Как исправить код, чтобы запрос возвратил мне Set-cookie? Запрос выводит следующее:

```
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Tue, 28 Nov 2017 12:49:34 GMT               
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8                                       
Content-Length: 17                                       
Connection: keep-alive                                  
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
```

Использование следующего кода выдает ту же информацию:

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

 RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("email", intent.getStringExtra("email"))
                        .add("first_name", intent.getStringExtra("firstName"))
                        .add("last_name", intent.getStringExtra("lastName"))
                        .add("password", etNewPassword.getText().toString())
                        .build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://api.yogamy.live/signup")
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                        Log.d("myLogs", "response onFailure");
                        Log.d("myLogs", "Throwable: " + e.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        Log.d("myLogs", "Responce " + response.headers());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Наверное нужно начать спрашивать разработчиков сервера, почему нет заголовка в ответе.

Comment: Eugene Krivenja, тут проблема в том, что responce почему то берется не полностью, а берется почему-то часть, далее там идет Set-Cookie

Comment: Куки надо ловить в interceptor'е okHttp. Они до ретрофита не доходят. Гуглите retorfit cookie например https://gist.github.com/tsuharesu/cbfd8f02d46498b01f1b

Comment: Yura Ivanov, сделала, исправила вопрос, не помогло

Comment: А это не кросдоменный доступ? Если это кросдоменный доступ то надо разрешить установку cookie + добавить разрешение на заголовок set-cookie + внести домен в список разрешенных. (в этом случае сервер тут вобще не при чем - это безопасность самого протокола http) Почитайте тут https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879567/retrofit-keeps-forgeting-my-cookies-android

```
//First create a new okhttpClient (this is okhttpnative)
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient(); //create OKHTTPClient
//create a cookieManager so your client can be cookie persistant
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
client.setCookieHandler(cookieManager); //finally set the cookie handler on client

//OkClient is retrofit default client, ofcourse since is based on OkHttClient
//you can decorate your existing okhttpclient with retrofit's okClient
OkClient serviceClient = new OkClient(client);

//finally set in your adapter
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("Some eNdpoint")
            .setClient(serviceClient)
            .build();
```